# Error al comprobar si el usuario ya existe

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo un formulario de registro que lo envio por AJAX y luego le pongo las condiciones. Aun no he puesto que lo inserte en la BD hasta que consiga que esto funciona. Por el momento me devuelve `error 500`.

Os pongo aquí el código:

```
  include "../conexion/conecta.php";


  else
  {
    mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Usuarios';
    $rec = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $verificar_usuario = 0;

    while($result = mysqli_fetch_object($rec))
    {
        if($result->Username == $_POST['Username'])
        {
            $verificar_usuario = 1;
        }
    }

    if($verificar_usuario == 0)
    {
        if($_POST['password'])
        {
          $nombre  = $_POST['nombre'];
          $apellidos  = $_POST['apellidos'];
          $email = $_POST['Username'];
          $password  = $_POST['password'];
          $dni = $_POST['dni'];
          $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
          $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
          $poblacion = $_POST['poblacion'];
          $postal = $_POST['postal'];
          $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
          $fecha = date('Y-m-d h:i:sa');

    echo "<div class=\"ui info message\" style=\"margin-bottom:1%;\">
            <div class=\"\">
              ¡Registrado correctamente!
            </div>
            <p>Todo correcto <strong>$nombre!</strong></p>
          </div>
          ";
        }

        else
        {
            echo '<span class="error">Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente.</span>';
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo '<span class="error">Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente.</span>';
    }
  }
```

No se si veis alguna anomalia que me este volviendo loco, gracias!

Comment: A la línea  `if($_POST['password'])` le falta comparar la contraseña proporcionada con la almacenada. ¿En qué línea te da ese error? ¿Por qué no buscas el usuario directamente en la base de datos en vez de traerlos todos del servidor mysql?

Comment: No se como hacerlo mejor la verdad, utilice un trozo de código que tengo antiguo con lo que se hacer hoy en día, pero sin exito, no se como hacerlo mejor gracias @DavidJP

Comment: Tu query a la db debe incluir el usuario y el password, y lo que verificas es si devuelve o no registros. no tiene sentido traer toda la base... ojala no tengas 100000 usuarios por los que iterar...

Comment: Vale ya solucione el problema de que no devolvia bien la respuesta, era por un fallo en la conexión!. Para comprobar directamente si esta el usuario en la BD es hacer 'SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Username = $email`  Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Sí, mucho mejor. Aún así, mejor con una consulta preparada... no te vayan a hacer inyección de código. Y, ya de paso, incluye la contraseña, que deberías almacenar cifrada

Comment: Ok! hecho! pero ahora como incorporo como comprobar la contraseña?? y por que es necesario? y lo de la insercción de código?. Pongo lo mio como respuesta para que veas si esta correcto

Answer (score 0):

El fallo lo tenia en la conexión, pongo aquí la modificación.

```
require_once "../conexion/conecta.php";

mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
$email = $_POST['Username'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Username = '$email'";
$rec = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);{
$verificar_usuario = 0;
while($result = mysqli_fetch_object($rec))
{
    if($result->Username == $_POST['Username'])
    {
        $verificar_usuario = 1;
    }
}

if($verificar_usuario == 0)
{

      $nombre  = $_POST['nombre'];
      $apellidos  = $_POST['apellidos'];
      $email = $_POST['Username'];
      $password  = $_POST['password'];
      $dni = $_POST['dni'];
      $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
      $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
      $poblacion = $_POST['poblacion'];
      $postal = $_POST['postal'];
      $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
      $fecha = date('Y-m-d h:i:sa');

echo "<div class=\"ui info message\" style=\"margin-bottom:1%;\">
        <div class=\"\">
          ¡Registrado correctamente!
        </div>
        <p>Todo correcto <strong>$nombre!</strong></p>
      </div>
      ";
    }

else
{
  echo "<div class=\"ui info message\" style=\"margin-bottom:1%;\">
          <div class=\"\">
            ¡El usuario ya existe!
          </div>
          <p>Prueba con un email diferente</p>
        </div>";
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Y cómo has resuelto el fallo en la conexión? ¿Con el `require_once`?

Comment: Si además de cambiar donde ponia `$con` por `$mysql`